# How to transform the input data based on specific values in the columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to transform the Input data based on the values 2 and -2 in the columns. The result should look like following.

```
Input:

Symbol   S1   S2   S3   S4   S5
ATAC     0     1    -1   -2   2
BHGV     1     1    -2    2   0
CCNL     2    -2     1    0   1
AGRN     0     2    -2    0   1

Result:

S1  2 CCNL
S2 -2 CCNL
S2  2 AGRN
S3 -2 BHGV
S3 -2 AGRN
S4 -2 ATAC
S4  2 BHGV
S5  2 ATAC
```

Thank you !!

Comment: Try with `melt` i.e `library(reshape2);melt(df1, id.var = "Symbol")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

akrun was a bit faster. If he doesnt post, here the complete answer:

```
library(data.table)
data <- fread("
      Symbol   S1   S2   S3   S4   S5
      ATAC     0     1    -1   -2   2
      BHGV     1     1    -2    2   0
      CCNL     2    -2     1    0   1
      AGRN     0     2    -2    0   1
      ")

melted <- melt(data, id.var = "Symbol")
melted <- melted[abs(melted$value) == 2, ]
```

Concerning the edit:

```
melted[melted == 2] <- "TWO"
melted[melted == -2] <- "MTWO"
```

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot. BTW in the result I want to name 2 as "TWO" and -2 as "MTWO". May I also know how to do this. If you want me to put this in the question I will do that. Thank you !!

Comment: Sure, would be good if you dit the questions accordingly!

Comment: Yes, Sorry for that. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

In base R with `stack` and `cbind`, you can do

```
# get 3 column data.frame
dat2 <- cbind(Symbol=dat$Symbol, stack(dat[-1]))
# drop unacceptable values
dat2[abs(dat2$values) > 1,]
   Symbol values ind
3    CCNL      2  S1
7    CCNL     -2  S2
8    AGRN      2  S2
10   BHGV     -2  S3
12   AGRN     -2  S3
13   ATAC     -2  S4
14   BHGV      2  S4
17   ATAC      2  S5
```

Comment: `>1` works of course in this subset of data, but imho it could be a bit risky in case there are absolute values > 2,...

Comment: That's a possibility of course. There are simple enough work-arounds like `abs(diff(dat2$values - 2) < 0.5)` or similar.